# rendered slugs are not correct in url django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Why do I always have an extra `%2F` in my generated slugs urls?

All the slugs are generating correctly below when I print them out in the terminal, but I don't know why the url has the extra `%2F`

Something is wrong somewhere but I cannot seem to spot it

In my view i am using `<a href = "{{ group.get_absolute_url }}">...` to get the slug. Now, this works but outputs the above problem. If i do `href = "{% url 'group' group.slug %}` this throws an error that it can't find a reverse match.

Example: title of group is `a group` the url will be `../%2Fgroup/a-group/`

in urls.py

```
 (r'^/group/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', "group"),
```

model

```
class BlogGroup(models.Model):

    title = BleachField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/group_images", default="uploads/group_images/none/none.jpg")
    created = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog.views.group", kwargs = {'slug':self.slug})
```

form

```
class BlogGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(BlogGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["title"].requried = True
        self.fields["image"].required = True
        self.fields["title"].widget = forms.TextInput()

    class Meta:
        model = BlogGroup
        fields = ["title", "image", "slug"]

    def save(self, commit = False):

        instance = super(BlogGroupForm, self).save(commit = False)
        return truncate_slug(instance, BlogGroup)
```

utils.py

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
import itertools

def truncate_slug(instance, arg):

    length = arg._meta.get_field('slug').max_length
    instance.slug = original_slug = slugify(instance.title)[:length]

    for x in itertools.count(1):
        if not arg.objects.filter(slug = instance.slug).exists():
            break
        instance.slug = "%s-%d" % (original_slug[:length - len(str(x)) -1], x)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a forward slash at the beginning of your regex. If you remove it, it should prevent the `%2f` (note that `%2f` is a url encoded forward slash).

```
url(r'^group/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', "group", name="group"),
```

Note that I have also

- removed `\d`, since `\w` already includes digits 0-9
- used `url()` (best practice for Django 1.8+) and named the url pattern. That should hopefully make reversing the url with the `{% url %}` tag work. Using `group.get_absolute_url` in your template is fine though, there's no need to use the url tag if you don't want to.